# How do I use dispatch_sync in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, grand-central-dispatch, firebase-realtime-database

this is my first time using stack overflow. I'm trying to get my program to wait for a query task to complete before moving on but I never get it to behave correctly. I put in print statements for debugging. The second and third print always comes before the first print. I think I don't really understand dispatch_sync very well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        let concurrentQueue = dispatch_queue_create(
            "com.x.TinderClone.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

        dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue) {
            usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("gender").queryEqualToValue(userInterestedIn).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
                for child in snapshot.children {
                    let uid = child.key!!
                    let gender = child.value!!["gender"] as! String
                    let id = child.value!!["id"] as! String
                    let interestedInWomen = child.value!!["interestedInWomen"] as! Bool
                    let name = child.value!!["name"] as! String

                    let potentialMatch = User(uid: uid, gender: gender, id: id, interestedInWomen: interestedInWomen, name: name)
                    listOfPotentialMatches.append(potentialMatch) //add the user struct to the array
                }

                print("First") // First print

                // ...
                }) { (error) in
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            print("Second") // Second Print
        }

        print("Third") //Third print
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, `dispatch_sync` isn't really helping you here. The problem is that the block you provide to`observeSingleEventOfType` is passed along as an argument—not executed synchronously—and will be executed whenever Firebase deems appropriate (presumably when the event occurs).

The easiest way to make `"Second"` and and `"Third"` print after `"First"` would be to put them *inside* the block, or to put them in a function that you call at the end of the block.

Answer (score 1):

`observeSingleEventOfType(:withBlock:)` takes a block, which includes most of the code you have written, including `print("First")`. *That* block is executed asynchronously.

In other words, your `dispatch_sync` code calls asynchronous code. The immediate `dispatch_sync` code runs immediately, but the async code it, in turn, calls, does not.

You'll have to assume that the block passed to `observeSingleEventOfType(:withBlock:)` may be executed out of order and design it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this same problem before. Recently I found a workaround using Timers to "wait" for your data to pull from Firebase. Here is a snippet that you could try to adapt to your actions after your Observe event:

var timer: NSTimer?

private func attemptReloadOfTable() {
        self.timer?.invalidate()

```
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.handleReloadTable), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```